# Can we export Katalon java code and reuse the code in a POM framework?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I would like to know if we can record and export the java code from the Katalon Studio recorder and import the code and use it in any POM framework?

Answer (score 0):

Code and elements by Katalon Studio can be used only in Katalon Studio. You can't extract it.